# Angular click on option of mat-autocomplete not triggered on first click

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm calling an API with a mat-autocomplete

My issue is that when I click on an option, the optionSelected is not trigger the first time. When I click again, it's working

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormlyBootstrapModule } from '@ngx-formly/bootstrap';
import { FieldType, FieldTypeConfig, FormlyModule } from '@ngx-formly/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { ISelectService, SelectItem, SelectItemServiceFactory } from '../../../services/select.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'state-select',
    imports: [
        MatInputModule,
        MatAutocompleteModule,
        FormlyModule,
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormlyBootstrapModule,
    ],
    standalone: true,
    providers: [SelectItemServiceFactory],
    styles: [
        `
        input {
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
    `,
    ],
    template: `
    <div>
        <label>{{ props.label }}</label>
        <input
            matInput
            [matAutocomplete]="auto"
            [formControl]="formControl"
            [formlyAttributes]="field"
            [placeholder]="props.placeholder || 'Selectionnez'"
        />
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="display" 
            (optionSelected)="handleOptionSelected($event.option.value)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let value of filter | async" [value]="value" >
                {{ value.title }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class StateSelectFieldType extends FieldType<FieldTypeConfig> implements OnInit {
    factory: SelectItemServiceFactory = new SelectItemServiceFactory();
    service: ISelectService | null = null

    filter: Observable<any> | undefined;

    ngOnInit() {
        // create service from factory
        this.service = this.factory.create(this.field.key as string);


        this.formControl.valueChanges.subscribe(async (value) => {
            const result = await this.service?.getData(value)
            this.filter = of(result)
            return result
        })
    }

    display(item: SelectItem): string {
        return item && item.title ? item.title : '';
    }

    handleOptionSelected(value: SelectItem) {
        this.field.formControl.setValue({ ...value, id: value.id })
    }
}
```

Comment: If you made a stackblitz it'd be easier for us to try things out on our side and help you out. Also keep in mind to make it as small as possible with just what's needed